# How do I delete an email address from Facebook App login page on Android?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-2, facebook

A mate recently used my mobile facebook app to log into his account. Now, I always get his email as the default when I go to log in to Facebook on Android App. Although not a big issue it is very frustrating.

I have deleted data and cache from App Settings. No go.

I have removed Accound from Account settings. No go.

I have set up another Gmail account for playstore and downloaded it through there. Still no change.

When I press sown on the email address whilst on log in page there is no option to remove address.

Please help as this is so frustrating.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First log out from your account and then follow the following steps as given on:
[https://m.facebook.com/help/670304209712363?helpref=uf_permalink
][1]

To remove an account from your phone or mobile device:

1. Go to the login screen on the Facebook app
2. Tap [Account to be removed]
3. Tap Remove account from device

For making for account as default just first logout and then login into your account.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial. You have to uninstall followed by the fresh installation of  the [Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana) app. You can **Clear Data** before uninstalling it but that's not necessary always.

> I have set up another Gmail account for playstore and downloaded it through there. Still no change.

Google Account doesn't controls how an app manages its data/settings, or for that matter, for any non-Google user app in your device. It is most likely that when you installed this app from another account, you didn't uninstalled it first, the reason why that troublesome email entry remained.

> I have removed Accoun[t] from Account settings. No go.

Since it is not mentioned which account, I assume: 1) its Google account which has already been discussed above; 2) its Facebook account, but because the data was cleared the app would fall back to log-in option. Don't know why the entry wasn't purged by clearing data.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I can't believe FB can be that sticky, intrusive and forceful like that. Just to remove an email at the login page of the app, one needs to uninstall the whole app and install again...